# check all boxes checked when click on parent checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have Parent1 and check box when i click on Parent1 check box all the child belongs to parent1 should to checked and  parent1 along with the checkbox should fadeout and again if i uncheck on any one of child  the parent1 along with the checkbox should reappear and the parent and child values are coming from database and they are in for each loop i.e first parent for each loop inside that child for each loop.

My code is in http://jsfiddle.net/mrc4N/3/

```
<div class="middle-right">
<ul class="mid-right-list">
<li><span id="Parent1a">+ Parent1<input name="parent" class="pc-box" type="checkbox"></span>
        <ul class="pa rplist">
<li value="1" class="parent1">- Child   1.1 <input class="cc-box" name="child" type="checkbox"></li>
<li value="2" class="parent1">- Child   1.2 <input class="cc-box" name="child" type="checkbox"></li>
<li value="3" class="parent1">- Child   1.3 <input class="cc-box" name="child" type="checkbox"></li>
            </ul>
              </li> 
<li><span id="Parent2a">+ Parent2<input name="parent" class="pc-box" type="checkbox"></span>
    <ul class="pb rplist">
<li value="1" class="parent2 c1">- Child 2.1 <input class="cc-box" name="child" type="checkbox"></li>
<li value="2" class="parent2 c2">-Child 2.2 <input class="cc-box" name="child" type="checkbox"></li>
<li value="3" class="parent2 c3">- Child    2.3 <input class="cc-box" name="child" type="checkbox"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><span id="Parent3a">+ Parent3<input name="parent" class="pc-box" type="checkbox"></span>
<ul class="pc rplist">
<li value="1" class="parent3 c1">-Child 3.1 <input class="cc-box" name="child" type="checkbox"></li>
<li value="2" class="parent3 c2">- Child    3.2 <input class="cc-box" name="child" type="checkbox"></li>
    <li value="3" class="parent3 c3">- Child    3.3 <input class="cc-box" name="child" type="checkbox"></li>
    </ul>               
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ugh.  Can't you code this yourself?

Comment: can u see plz its in jsfiddle

Comment: You have no jQuery at all in the fiddle.  Please try something.

Comment: can u tell me how it can done using jquery

Comment: you should use jquery

Comment: have you tried anything using jQuery - to start with jquery use http://learn.jquery.com and http://api.jquery.com

Comment: No.  You have the docs for that.

Comment: yes i have done many thinks but it is creating bit complexity can u plz help me

Comment: did you try a change handler... what is the complexity you are seeing here

Comment: http://tech.tiffanyandjeremy.com/Articles/Two-level-JQuery-check-and-uncheck-all-child-checkboxes-of-a-parent-checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"when i click on Parent1 check box all the child belongs to parent1 should to checked and parent1 along with the checkbox should fadeout and again if i uncheck on any one of child the parent1 along with the checkbox should reappear"*

The following is one way to do that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
    $(".pc-box").click(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(this).closest("li").find(".cc-box").prop("checked", true);
            $(this).parent().fadeOut();
        }  
    });
    $(".cc-box").click(function() {
        if (!this.checked)
            $(this).closest("ul").prev().fadeIn().find(".pc-box").prop("checked", false);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mrc4N/4/

> *"and the parent and child values are coming from database and they are in for each loop"*

I don't understand how that information is relevant to what you are asking, so I'm going to go ahead and ignore it.

Documentation for all of the jQuery methods I've used is available at [the jQuery website](http://api.jquery.com/).

**Homework for you: look up every jQuery method used in my code. And do some [jQuery tutorials](http://learn.jquery.com/).**

Comment: You're welcome - _if_ you do the homework that I've assigned you.

Comment: when i check indiviually all  the child checkboxes the parent is not checked and it is not fading out

Comment: Right. Because that's a requirement not stated in the question so I didn't allow for it in my code. It was, arguably, implied by your original question, or at least a logical next step to your question, but since you didn't explicitly state it I decided not to spend time coding it. And, sorry, I don't have time to do it now. Why don't you start with the code I've given you, try to understand it, and add to it yourself. StackOverflow isn't the McDonald's drive-through window where you order anything you want; we're here to help you with your problems, not do it all for you.

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like this:

```
$('[type="checkbox"][name="parent"]').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next('ul').find('li input').prop('checked',this.checked);
});
```

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DEhP7/)

Answer (score 4):

The basic logic here is to find the parent checkboxes(in this case they have the class `pc-box`) the hook a change handler to it.

Then you can find the other child checkbox elements within the same li as the changed parent checkbox and set its checked property as the same as the parents status

```
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function () {
    //change handler for parent checkboxes
    $('.pc-box').change(function () {
        //update the checked status of all child checkeboxes in the same li
        $(this).closest('li').find('ul input').prop('checked', this.checked)
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Sk23Q/)

- [Dom Ready Handler](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)
- [class-selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector) - to find the parent checkboxes using class
- [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change)
- [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest) - to find the `li` in which the changed `li` belongs to
- [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find) - finds the child checkboxes in the same `li`
- [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) - change the checked property

Answer (score 1):

**Try this work fine:**

```
$('[type="checkbox"][name="parent"]').on("click", function() {
  var all = $(this);
  $('input:checkbox').each(function() {
       $(this).prop("checked", all.prop("checked"));
  });
});
```

Comment: Note that you don't need the `.each()` loop. `$('input:checkbox').prop("checked", all.prop("checked"))` will have the same effect because jQuery loops internally.